# Sum column, between dates fields in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to learn mongoose, I come from a SQL background and I am having difficulties figuring out how this works.

So I am essentially trying to run this SQL code in Mongoose

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(comdataPurchase)
              FROM fuel566243
              WHERE fuelDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate';";
```

But I cannot get it to work properly for me in mongoose. Here is what I have so far.

```
FuelReceipt.aggregate([{$match:{date:{$gte: fuelStart, $lt: fuelEnd}}},
                {$group:{truckNumber: truckNumber, dieselGallons:{'$sum': '$count'}}}]).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

Thank you in advance for your help <3

edit:-------------

This works:

```
FuelReceipt.aggregate([
                {$group:{_id: '$truckNumber', 
                         dieselGallons:{$sum: '$dieselGallons'}}}]).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
                });
```

This gives empty array:

```
FuelReceipt.aggregate([
                {$match:{date:{$gte: fuelStart, $lte: fuelEnd}}},
                {$group:{_id: '$truckNumber', 
                         dieselGallons:{$sum: '$dieselGallons'}}}]).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
                });
```

edit 2:----------------

I figured it out, had to change the data type for the start and end dates.

```
FuelReceipt.aggregate([
                {$match:{date:{$gte: new Date(fuelStart), $lte: new Date(fuelEnd)}}},
                {$group:{_id: '$truckNumber', 
                         fuelCost:{$sum: '$fuelCost'}}}]).exec(function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('Error Fetching Model');
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    res.send(data);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null));
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "between" part is implemented correctly however [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) requires `_id` value. You can set it to `null` if you want to get single aggregate for entire set of documents:

```
{$group: { _id: null, dieselGallons: {'$sum': '$comdataPurchase'}}}
```

Comment: So, I got the aggregation function working properly when I delete the $match portion. 

But as soon as I add back in the $match portion, it console.logs and empty array.

Comment: @TheTravelingCoder try to make sure that types match like if date is ISODate then you should pass ISOData not string and vice versa